# How to make a PWA landing page different from the site landing page when offline?

Tags: html, browser, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

My application has historically worked by having a landing page that's shown to everyone. There's a login button and if you click it, it shows a dialog for credentials, and when you enter them successfully, you are logged in and redirected to the home page for your login type.

In a PWA situation, once I know who the user is, I'd like to put an "install this as an app" button on the home page, and then since I know who the user is, there's no need to show the general landing page and ask for a login. I'd like to just remember the user and go right to their home page.

I could cache the login information in local storage, but I want to do this ONLY when offline and I think the PWA would still show the default landing page and, at best, immediately redirect to the home page, and this would look bad.

Is there a way to set this up the way I would like to?

Answer (score 1):

In order to install a PWA you created a manifest file and a service worker. When the application is successfully installed (added to home screen) the service worker comes to action. The service worker will be serving all the files you have declared either online or offline. This means it will be serving the manifest file.

In the manifest file you can add the start url which is going to be the one defined route, in this case go directly to your app instead of the landing page. In your manifest file just add:

"start_url": "../joshuaFrankApp"
or
"start_url": "../joshuaFrankApp.html"

Whenever the app is installed (doesn't matter if it the user is online or offline) it will be redirected to the page you wanted.

Extra information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/start_url